# Grid based substitution cipher (which can be customised)

Tags: python

Beginner here, my code is here: https://github.com/infinitless/MatrixEncryption

Reproducing all of it here:

```
import random
import re
import math
import string

# Define Reference Grid

values = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"],
    ["m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"],
    ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x"],
    ["y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3"],
    ["4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
]

myrows = ["1", "2", "1,1", "1,2", "2,1", "2,2"]
mycolumns = ["1", "2", "1,1", "1,2", "2,1", "2,2"]
positions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


# The encoded text for any character (alphabet or number) = column + row, joined together
# Punctuation and spaces are ignored
# So "abc" as per Reference grid = 111211,1

# Define single row rotation

def rotaterow(myvalues, rowindex, rotation):
    rotatedrow = ""
    newrow = myvalues[rowindex]
    for nN in range(0, 6):
        rotatedrow = newrow[rotation % 6:] + newrow[:rotation % 6]
    return rotatedrow


# Define single column rotation

def rotatecolumn(myvalues, columnindex, rotation):
    rotatedcolumn = ""
    newcolumn = [column[columnindex] for column in myvalues]
    for nm in range(0, 6):
        rotatedcolumn = newcolumn[rotation % 6:] + newcolumn[:rotation % 6]
    return rotatedcolumn


# Find a particular character and return its cipher

def findme(mychar, myvalues):
    cipher_string = ""
    for rows in myvalues:
        if mychar in rows:
            cipher_string = (mycolumns[myvalues.index(rows)]) + (myrows[rows.index(mychar)])
    return str(cipher_string)


# Read all decimal places of PI from the file
# and store as a string of 1 Million digits

with open("piDigits.txt", 'r') as f:
    pidecimals = f.read()
f.close()


# Rotate the Reference grid in a random fashion
# Generate a Random Number
# Go to that position in pidecimlas
# Pick up N digits from that place in pidecimals
# such that the number of digits in the random number
# plus the number of digits from pidecimals = 12.
# If someone has the PiDigits file and the randomseed
# they will know which digits have been chosen.
# Now rotate the grid as per the combination of random number
# and the number of randomly chosen digits of Pi

def randomrotation():
    myrandomseed = random.randint(1, len(pidecimals) - 12)
    length_randomseed = len(str(myrandomseed))
    deficit = 12 - length_randomseed

    pistring = ""
    for nmn in range(myrandomseed - 1, myrandomseed - 1 + deficit):
        pistring += pidecimals[nmn]
    rotationkey = (str(myrandomseed) + pistring)

    rotatedrow1 = rotaterow(values, 0, int(rotationkey[0]))
    rotatedrow2 = rotaterow(values, 1, int(rotationkey[1]))
    rotatedrow3 = rotaterow(values, 2, int(rotationkey[2]))
    rotatedrow4 = rotaterow(values, 3, int(rotationkey[3]))
    rotatedrow5 = rotaterow(values, 4, int(rotationkey[4]))
    rotatedrow6 = rotaterow(values, 5, int(rotationkey[5]))
    rotatedrows = [rotatedrow1, rotatedrow2, rotatedrow3, rotatedrow4, rotatedrow5, rotatedrow6]

    rotatedcolumn1 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 0, int(rotationkey[6]))
    rotatedcolumn2 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 1, int(rotationkey[7]))
    rotatedcolumn3 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 2, int(rotationkey[8]))
    rotatedcolumn4 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 3, int(rotationkey[9]))
    rotatedsolumn5 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 4, int(rotationkey[10]))
    rotatedcolumn6 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 5, int(rotationkey[11]))
    rotatedcolumns = [rotatedcolumn1, rotatedcolumn2, rotatedcolumn3, rotatedcolumn4, rotatedsolumn5, rotatedcolumn6]

    return rotatedcolumns, myrandomseed


# Rotate the reference grid if private key is supplied

def rotateme(privatekey):
    rotatedrow1 = rotaterow(values, 0, int(privatekey[0]))
    rotatedrow2 = rotaterow(values, 1, int(privatekey[1]))
    rotatedrow3 = rotaterow(values, 2, int(privatekey[2]))
    rotatedrow4 = rotaterow(values, 3, int(privatekey[3]))
    rotatedrow5 = rotaterow(values, 4, int(privatekey[4]))
    rotatedrow6 = rotaterow(values, 5, int(privatekey[5]))
    rotatedrows = [rotatedrow1, rotatedrow2, rotatedrow3, rotatedrow4, rotatedrow5, rotatedrow6]

    rotatedcolumn1 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 0, int(privatekey[6]))
    rotatedcolumn2 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 1, int(privatekey[7]))
    rotatedcolumn3 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 2, int(privatekey[8]))
    rotatedcolumn4 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 3, int(privatekey[9]))
    rotatedsolumn5 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 4, int(privatekey[10]))
    rotatedcolumn6 = rotatecolumn(rotatedrows, 5, int(privatekey[11]))
    rotatedcolumns = [rotatedcolumn1, rotatedcolumn2, rotatedcolumn3, rotatedcolumn4, rotatedsolumn5, rotatedcolumn6]

    return rotatedcolumns


# Encoding Function as per Rotated Grid

def encode(myplain_text, rotatedgrid):
    mycipher_text = ""
    for letter in myplain_text:
        dummy = findme(letter, rotatedgrid)
        mycipher_text += dummy
    return str(mycipher_text)


# Find User private key for Decoding

def findkey(userkey):
    userkeylength = len(userkey)
    userdeficit = 12 - userkeylength
    pistring = ""
    for nmm in range(int(userkey) - 1, int(userkey) - 1 + userdeficit):
        pistring += pidecimals[nmm]
    rotationkey = (str(userkey) + pistring)
    return rotationkey


# Breakdown cipher text into chunks

def breakcode(usercipher):
    decipher = re.compile(r'\w,\w|\w')
    broken = decipher.findall(usercipher)
    return broken


# Return number of characters in plain text

def countcipher(somecipher_text):
    test = [breakcode(somecipher_text)]
    return len(test[0]) / 2


# Create pairs of (column,row) from cipher_text
# Create the rotated grid based on private key
# Convert pairs into positions

def decode(somecipher_text, userkey):
    test = []
    flat_list = []

    mygrid = creategrid(userkey)

    test.append(breakcode(somecipher_text))

    for sublist in test:
        for item in sublist:
            flat_list.append(item)

    listpairs = [flat_list[ii:ii + 2] for ii in range(0, len(flat_list), 2)]

    columnpositions = [a[0] for a in listpairs]
    rowpositions = [a[1] for a in listpairs]

    columnindices = []
    rowindices = []

    for jj in range(len(columnpositions)):
        for j in range(len(mycolumns)):
            if columnpositions[jj] == mycolumns[j]:
                columnindices.append(mycolumns.index(columnpositions[jj]))

    for jj in range(len(rowpositions)):
        for j in range(len(myrows)):
            if rowpositions[jj] == myrows[j]:
                rowindices.append(myrows.index(rowpositions[jj]))

    my_decoded_text = ""
    for m in range(len(rowindices)):
        my_decoded_text += (mygrid[columnindices[m]][rowindices[m]])

    return my_decoded_text


# Generate keys equal to number of characters in string

def genkeylist(inputstring):
    pistring = ""
    keyarray = []
    myrandomseed = random.randint(1, len(pidecimals) - 12)
    length_randomseed = len(str(myrandomseed))
    deficit = 12 - length_randomseed

    for n in range(myrandomseed - 1, myrandomseed - 1 + deficit):
        pistring += pidecimals[n]
    keystring = str(myrandomseed) + pistring
    keyuserstring = str(myrandomseed) + pistring

    myfirstkey = int(keystring)

    for char in range(len(inputstring)):
        mynextkey = (myfirstkey ** (1 / 2)) % 1000000
        mynextkey = mynextkey - int(mynextkey)
        mynextkey = (str(mynextkey)[2:][:6])
        keyarray.append(str(mynextkey))
        myfirstkey = int(mynextkey)

    return keystring, keyarray


# Create the grid from user private key

def creategrid(userkey):
    thiskey = findkey(userkey)
    rotatedgrid = rotateme(thiskey)
    return rotatedgrid


# Remove spaces and punctuation from a string

def cleanstring(mystring):
    mystring = mystring.replace(" ", "")
    mystring = mystring.lower()
    mystring = mystring.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return mystring


# Ensure number of rotations within a string
# is proportional to the length of string.
# This also limits number of keys if the message
# is too short.

def chopstring(some_str):
    tempx = len(some_str) ** (1 / 4)
    tempy = random.randint(0, 1)
    if tempy == 1:
        mynumkeys = math.ceil(tempx)
    else:
        mynumkeys = math.floor(tempx)
    stringparts = math.ceil((len(some_str) / mynumkeys))
    my_chunks = [some_str[k:k + stringparts] for k in range(0, len(some_str), stringparts)]
    return my_chunks, mynumkeys


# Main Program

levelchoice = input("Type 1 for Easy, 2 for Moderate or 3 for Hard: ")

if levelchoice == "1":
    print("You chose EASY level encryption: ")
    choice = input("Write 1 to Encode or 0 to Decode: ")

    if choice == "1":
        plain_text = input("Enter message to be encoded: ")
        plain_text = cleanstring(plain_text)
        finalgrid, key = randomrotation()
        print(f"The Encoded message is: {encode(plain_text, finalgrid)}")
        print(f"Your Private Key is: {key}")
    elif choice == "0":
        cipher_text = input("Enter message to be decoded: ")
        cipher_key = input("Enter Private Key: ")
        print(f"The decoded message is: {decode(cipher_text, cipher_key)}")
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")

elif levelchoice == "2":
    print("You chose MODERATE level encryption: ")
    choice = input("Write 1 to Encode or 0 to Decode: ")

    if choice == "1":

        str_coded = []
        keylist = []
        chunklengths = []
        codelist = []
        str_final = ""

        plain_text = input("Enter message to be encoded: ")
        plain_text = cleanstring(plain_text)
        chunks, numkeys = chopstring(plain_text)

        for i in range(0, len(chunks)):
            newgrid, randomseed = randomrotation()
            str_coded.append(encode(chunks[i], newgrid) + ".")
            keylist.append(str(randomseed))
            codelist.append(str_coded[i])
            chunklengths.append(len(str_coded[i]))
            str_final += (codelist[i])
        str_final.rstrip(".")
        print(f"The Encoded message is : {str_final}")
        print(f"Your Keys are: {keylist}")

    elif choice == "0":
        cipher_chunks = []
        decoded_text = []
        sent_str = ""
        cipher_text = input("Enter message to be decoded: ")
        cipher_text = cipher_text[:-1]
        cipher_chunks.append(cipher_text.split("."))
        for i in range(0, len(cipher_chunks[0])):
            cipher_key = input(f"Enter Private Key number {i + 1}: ")
            decoded_text.append(decode(cipher_chunks[0][i], cipher_key))
        for i in decoded_text:
            sent_str += str(i)
        print(f"The Decoded message is : {sent_str}")
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")

elif levelchoice == "3":
    print("You chose HARD level encryption.")
    choice = input("Write 1 to Encode or 0 to Decode: ")

    cipher_list = []
    ciphertext = ""

    if choice == "1":
        plain_text = input("Enter message to be encoded: ")
        plain_text = cleanstring(plain_text)

        keyarray = genkeylist(plain_text)

        for n in range(0, len(plain_text)):
            newgengrid = creategrid(keyarray[1][n])
            cipher_list.append(encode(plain_text[n], newgengrid))
            ciphertext += str(cipher_list[n])
        print(f"The Encoded message is: {ciphertext}")
        print(f"Your Master Key is : {keyarray[0]}")

    elif choice == "0":
        actualstring = ""
        keyarray = []
        answerstring = []
        codechunks = []
        decoded_text = ""
        gridlist = [[]]
        codepairs = []

        ciphertext = input("Enter message to be decoded: ")
        actual_length = int(countcipher(ciphertext))
        firstkey = input("Enter Master Key: ")

        for i in range(0, actual_length):
            nextkey = (int(firstkey) ** (1 / 2)) % 1000000
            nextkey = nextkey - int(nextkey)
            nextkey = (str(nextkey)[2:][:6])
            keyarray.append(str(nextkey))
            firstkey = int(nextkey)

        for j in range(0, len(keyarray)):
            gridlist.append(creategrid(keyarray[j]))

        codechunks = breakcode(ciphertext)
        for ll in range(0, len(codechunks), 2):
            codepairs.append((codechunks[ll] + codechunks[ll + 1]))

        listpairs = [codechunks[ii:ii + 2] for ii in range(0, len(codechunks), 2)]

        columnpositions = [a[0] for a in listpairs]
        rowpositions = [a[1] for a in listpairs]

        columnindices = []
        rowindices = []

        for jj in range(len(columnpositions)):
            for j in range(len(mycolumns)):
                if columnpositions[jj] == mycolumns[j]:
                    columnindices.append(mycolumns.index(columnpositions[jj]))

        for jj in range(len(rowpositions)):
            for j in range(len(myrows)):
                if rowpositions[jj] == myrows[j]:
                    rowindices.append(myrows.index(rowpositions[jj]))

        for kk in range(0, actual_length):
            decoded_text += (gridlist[kk + 1][columnindices[kk]][rowindices[kk]])

        print(f"The Decoded message is : {decoded_text}")

    else:
        print("Invalid input.")

else:
    print("Invalid input.")
```

I am looking for constructive feedback on the cipher (especially the hard mode).

1. Feedback from someone using frequency analysis to crack it
2. Feedback from someone using brute force to guess the key

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to include your _entire_ code in your post next time. What if your github repo changes, or you update your code? That will render this question meaningless =)

Comment: What Cipher is this?  Polybius cipher? It does not look like the Playfair cipher.

Comment: I don't know if it has a name. It's my own invention but the result is a pseudo-random substitution. The inspiration was the story "The Gold Bug" by Edgar Allan Poe.

Answer (score 1):

## Redundant calculations

```
    for nN in range(0, 6):
        rotatedrow = newrow[rotation % 6:] + newrow[:rotation % 6]
...
    for nm in range(0, 6):
        rotatedcolumn = newcolumn[rotation % 6:] + newcolumn[:rotation % 6]
```

Since the result computed in the loop does not change the values used in the calculations, the second and subsequent iterations do not produce a different result from the first.  The `for` loops can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Sort your imports in alphabetical order.

Add typehints. If you keep your existing data structures, it would be useful to alias `char = str` and then hint that, to make it clear that you have (for example) lists of lists of characters.

`values` should never change, so should be rephrased as an immutable tuple. Moreover, the more natural way of expressing a sequence of sequences of characters is as a tuple of strings, i.e.

```
values = (
    "abcdef",
    "ghijkl",
    "mnopqr",
    "stuvwx",
    "yz0123",
    "456789",
)
```

`my_rows`, `my_columns` should similarly be changed into immutable tuples of strings.

Delete `positions` because it wasn't used.

All of your names looking like `rotaterow` should be `rotate_row` by PEP8.

`rotaterow`'s algorithm doesn't make much sense, because you're overwriting `rotatedcolumn` on every loop iteration - so it would be equivalent to only running the last iteration and skipping everything else. Not sure what you actually wanted to do here.

`str(cipher_string)` is redundant; that's already a string.

You may want to comment that `piDigits` is expected to contain digits of pi with no `.` decimal place; otherwise your algorithm will blow up.

Whenever you see a comment before a function describing that function, move it to a docstring, as in

```
def random_rotation() -> tuple[
    list[list[char]],  # rotated columns
    int,               # random seed
]:
    """
    Rotate the Reference grid in a random fashion
    Generate a Random Number
    Go to that position in pidecimlas
    Pick up N digits from that place in pidecimals
    such that the number of digits in the random number
    plus the number of digits from pidecimals = 12.
    If someone has the PiDigits file and the randomseed
    they will know which digits have been chosen.
    Now rotate the grid as per the combination of random number
    and the number of randomly chosen digits of Pi
    """
```

Code like this:

```
    rotatedrow1 = rotaterow(values, 0, int(rotationkey[0]))
    rotatedrow2 = rotaterow(values, 1, int(rotationkey[1]))
    rotatedrow3 = rotaterow(values, 2, int(rotationkey[2]))
    rotatedrow4 = rotaterow(values, 3, int(rotationkey[3]))
    rotatedrow5 = rotaterow(values, 4, int(rotationkey[4]))
    rotatedrow6 = rotaterow(values, 5, int(rotationkey[5]))
```

should be replaced with a loop that iterates six times.

Your iterated string concatenation here:

```
    pistring = ""
    for nmm in range(int(userkey) - 1, int(userkey) - 1 + userdeficit):
        pistring += pidecimals[nmm]
```

would be better phrased as a `''.join` call, which will execute more quickly.

The outer parens on `rotationkey = (str(userkey) + pistring)` are redundant.

I think you expect `countcipher` to return an `int`, but currently it returns a `float`. You should be using `//` floor division instead.

```
    keyuserstring = str(myrandomseed) + pistring
```

is never used so delete it.

Consider breaking up your main program into three separate methods - `easy`, `moderate` and `hard` - which are invoked by a `main` method, in turn invoked by a `__main__` guard.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. Looking for feedback on these lines : Feedback from someone using frequency analysis to crack it. Feedback from someone using brute force to guess the key(s). In other words is anyone able to crack the message without tge associated key(s)? Thanks!